# Problem running Docker with com.github.dockerjava

Tags: java, docker, docker-api

I am trying to use docker and run my image with this Java Library: com.github.dockerjava

Here is the code :

```java
import com.github.dockerjava.api.DockerClient;
import com.github.dockerjava.api.command.CreateContainerCmd;
import com.github.dockerjava.api.command.PullImageResultCallback;
import com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.NotFoundException;
import com.github.dockerjava.api.model.Container;
import com.github.dockerjava.api.model.ContainerNetwork;
import com.github.dockerjava.api.model.Image;
import com.github.dockerjava.core.DockerClientBuilder;

public static void main(String[] args) {
        String containerName = "mycontainer_name";
        String dockerImage = "myimage";

        // Get the Docker client
        System.out.println("Get Docker client");
        DockerClient dockerClient = DockerClientBuilder.getInstance().build();

        // Check if the container is already running
        if (dockerContainerExists(containerName, dockerClient)) {
            System.out.println("Container already exists");
            dockerStop(containerName, dockerClient);
            DockerRm(containerName, dockerClient);
        }

        CreateContainerCmd createContainer = dockerClient
                .createContainerCmd(dockerImage).withName(containerName);
        createContainer.withTty(true);
        createContainer.exec();

        dockerClient.killContainerCmd(containerName).exec();
        dockerClient.removeContainerCmd(containerName).exec();

        // runDataGenerator(new Pcap(), args);
    }
```

Here is my pom.xml dependency :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.docker-java</groupId>
    <artifactId>docker-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

But I get this error :

```bash
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported protocol scheme: npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine
        at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.JerseyDockerHttpClient.<init>(JerseyDockerHttpClient.java:225)
        at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.JerseyDockerHttpClient.<init>(JerseyDockerHttpClient.java:49)
        at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.JerseyDockerHttpClient$Builder.build(JerseyDockerHttpClient.java:124)
        at com.github.dockerjava.core.DockerClientBuilder.build(DockerClientBuilder.java:106)
        at org.package.main(Pcap.java:1108)
```

I am on Windows and have Docker Desktop running (by the way it works perfectly on Linux) and I saw the same type of error for other people but I couldn't find any answers.
If someone has the answer to this or has faced the same problem I am up for answers...